# Why can't users download files from my codeigniter application which i specified?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, laravel

I have one function in my controller that lets users download files in a specified folder from the server in my codeigniter application...
It doesn't download in the proper manner...
Here is the code if anyone can help me...

```
    foreach ($temp as $thePath) {

        // Create recursive directory iterator
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($thePath), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
        );

        foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
            if ($file->getFilename() != '.' && $file->getFilename() != '..') {

                // Get real path for current file
                $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
                $temp = explode("/", $name);
                array_shift($temp);

                $newName = implode("/", $temp);

                $_allFiles[] = array('filePath' => $filePath, 'newName' => $newName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here $temp contains all the path that i want to let the user download when they click button....

- $temp[0]=elements/bootstrap
- $temp[1]=elements/cs
- $temp[2]=elements/fonts
- $temp[3]=elements/images
- $temp[4]=elements/js

But when they download the file, they get different structure like this...

1>>>>
-elements
   -bootstratp

-fonts

-index.html

2>>>>

-elements
   -bootstratp

-css

-fonts

-images

-js

===> I don't know why i get either the first structure or second structure..
If anyone can help me please..

Comment: What directory structure you want ?

Comment: I want everything in elements folder...except index.html

Comment: `$temp` only contains the path to those directories, which you want  o download. right ?

Comment: yeah... It contains the path where i have stored those folder which i want to let users download...